# Direct S3 upload with Flutter and node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, flutter

I have a node.js REST API that can save user "posts" and then retrieve the data in a JSON API format which is great but I also need to append some images to each "post". How do I upload directly from my Flutter client to AWS S3, the problem is I'm kind of confused on how to handle this because I don't wanna push the images trough my server because of the load. I saw some plugins on how to upload images but the problem is that I need to save the image links in an array for the "post" so when the user opens it it loads up the images but how can I get the links saved to my API if I first need to upload the images and get the links back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the idea is, your nodejs code has to generate presigned url for each file and send it as part of the json.

Presigned URL is the safest method to access the files from S3 without making the S3 bucket public.

here is a nodejs code example to get the URLs,

```
const getPresignedUrl = async (fileName, fileType) => {

  const S3_BUCKET = 'my-s3-bucket'
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();  // Create a new instance of S3

  // Set up the payload of what we are sending to the S3 api
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 5000,
    //ContentType: fileType,
    // ACL: 'public-read',
    ContentType: 'application/octet-stream'
  };
  // Make a request to the S3 API to get a signed URL which we can use to upload our file

  try {
    const data = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', s3Params);
    const returnData = {
      signedRequest: data,
      url: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
    };

    return returnData;

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err: ', err);
  }
}
```

hope this helps.